# How do I serve a create-react-app as a subdirectory of a larger website?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app

I've got a relatively basic question about how to structure javascript code when creating an app with React.

I want to have a single-page app embedded within a multi-page website. I might have, for instance, a homepage, an about page, a registration page, etc., all of which are served by a node server running Express. They have nothing to do with React. I am also using passport, which is serving its own pages for authentication (local login, social sign in, logout, etc...) Additionally, I have a graphql API running at /api/ on the server.

I also want, on the same website, to have a react app served at `/embed/*` (where the base url of the react app is `https://mywebsite.com/embed/`, and there are many sub-pages handled by react-router).

**How do I serve the React app, created using `create-react-app`, as a subdirectory of a larger site -- in both development and production?** (Cookies should be shared between the react app and the main site.)

I've successfully used the "proxy" option in `create-react-app` to connect to the API (running on port 3001) from the react app (running on port 3000). However, the proxy does not seem to be able to forward URLs which are entered in the browser by a user. (For example: If I access `localhost:3000/api/` using `fetch` within my code, it forwards to `localhost:3001/api/` as desired. However, if I enter that same URL into the address bar, it doesn't get redirected. Instead, my react app loads. This makes sense, but isn't the behavior I want.)

Comment: Will it be served by the same Express app? You can put the react app anywhere and serve them statically (ie, `app.use('/embed', express.static('./my/react/app'))`

Comment: I had tried a solution like that, using webpack to bundle the react app into a single bundle.js, but got myself woefully confused. Should my react app be its own npm module (with its own package.json)? Its own git repo? Should it be nested as a subdirectory inside the express app or housed separately? How do I deal with static files? Do they live inside the react app to be bundled by webpack or do they live a level up, served by the "parent" express app? How do I serve the bundle.js in html? Do I have a hand-written static html file which loads the JS, or is the html generated by webpack too?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any things about package.json and other stuff. Just if you have any assets like image, fonts, ... they should be included in the build folder(or dist folder if you used **dist** instead of **build**) that includes bundle.js.

By using create-react-app you will have these files in the build folder:

- asset-manifest.json
- favicon
- index.html
- manifest.json
- static folder
- and other static files that you may be used in your app and put them in the public folder in development mode

All of your code will bundle and you don't need to have package.json, ...

But if you are not using creat-react-app it will be different and you need to include your bundle.js in your index.html

But with CRA you don't everything will be automatic and you don't need to do extra.

This link help you to routing:
[Create-React-App in production: Routes not found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52179111/9161843)

In the server you can serve the index.html like this:

```
let root = path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build');
app.use(express.static(root));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
if (req.method === 'GET' && req.accepts('html') && !req.is('json') && 
 !req.path.includes('.')) {
   res.sendFile('index.html', { root });
 } else next();
 });
```

Hope this help you